# Facebook developer FQL fan gate

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have fan gate using FQL. It works fine, but some user doesn't have access to content even if the have liked the page.
Here is my code:

```
$result = $facebook->api(array(
  "method"    => "fql.query",
  "query"     => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=$user_id AND page_id=$page_id"
));

if(count($result)){
   echo "FAN CONTENT";
}
else {
   echo "NON-FAN CONTENT";
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I guarantee! with some users fan gate works fine, with others - doesn't :X

Comment: Here is my app: https://apps.facebook.com/kartuligvarisistoria/

Comment: As Sahil said, this can't work because you're not requesting the "user_likes" permission... Are you using your app as Page Tab app?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't use page tab, and I request user_likes permission, here is my login_url code: $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
 'scope' => 'publish_actions', 'user_likes', ));

Comment: Here is my app: https://apps.facebook.com/kartuligvarisistoria/